# need to highlight cell if date indicated is less than or equal to 2 business day of date today

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

need help on conditional formatting on how to highlight cells that has a value of a date that is less than or equal to 2 business days from today.

example 1:
Date Input: Friday, January 10, 2020
Date today: Wednesday, January 8, 2020
value is equal to 2 business day from today so it should be highlighted.

example 2:
Date Input: Monday, January 13, 2020
Date today: Thursday, January 9, 2020
value is equal to 2 business day from today so it should be highlighted.

Please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: What are you considering a business day?  Simply Monday - Friday?

Comment: Yes business days are mondays to fridays

Answer (score 1):

Create a new conditional formatting rule based on a formula.  For the formula you can use the [`NETWORKDAYS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) worksheet function.  Apply whatever formatting you want.  In my example I apply a yellow fill to the cell if the rule matches.  You need to use the absolute value of what `NETWORKDAYS` returns, thus the use of `ABS`.  Use `NOW()` in the formula to get the current date.

[image]

Then make sure the rule applies to your specific range:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this... it helped me with the problem i just need to check if the formula would take effect if today is a friday and the date indicated is on monday

Comment: cause i cant change the date on my laptop due to restrictions